# phpmail formatear mail html con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, email, mail

tengo una web que enviar por mail las consultas, pero me gustaría formatearla con Bootstrap, hacerla mas bonita. El problema que tengo es que abriéndola diréctamente se ve bien pero al enviarla por mail no carga el bootstrap. Sin embargo al mirar el código del correo si me sale el link al bootstrap.min.css.

Alguien me puede echar una mano? GRACIAS Adjunto el código para que podáis verlo.

Este es el archivo mail.php con la función de envio del mail

```
<?php 
function seguimientoMail($tecnico,$agente, $id, $zona, $fechahora, $diavisita, $horavisita, $estadoaveria, $contacto,$direccion,$cp, $poblacion, $provincia, $telefonofijo, $telefonomovil, $marca, $aparato, $descripcion, $observaciones,$seguimiento)
{
    $to      = "yyy@yyy.com";
    $remitente = 'xxx@xxx.es';
    $subject = $zona . " - " . $estadoaveria . " - Visita: ".$diavisita." - ".$horavisita;
    $message = file_get_contents("./assets/templates/seguimientoMail.html");
    //$message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='es'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name='viewport'
    // content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'><title>Document</title>";
    //$message .= "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/css/fontawesome.min
    //.css'><link rel='stylesheet' href='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel='stylesheet' href='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/css/styles.css'><script src='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script><script src='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/js/fontawesome.min.js'></script><script src='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script><script src='http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/js/scripts.js'></script>";
    //$message .= "</head><body><div class='col-lg-12 text-primary'><h1 align='center'>Incidencia número ".$id
    $headers = 'From: app@app.serviciotecnicopro.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: noreply@app.serviciotecnicopro.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= "From: " . $remitente . " \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $remitente . "\r\n"; //La dirección por defecto si se responde el email enviado.
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        //echo "Correo enviado a $to <br>";
        //echo $message
    } else {
        echo "No se puede enviar correo";
    }
}
?>
```

Este es el mail formateado, archivo seguimientoMail.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Resguardo Seguimiento</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tecnico.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/css/styles.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://tecnico.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
            <style>
                body{
                    align-content: center;
                    margin: 7% 25%;
                }
                .jumbotron{
                    padding:2rem 1rem;
                    margin-bottom:2rem;
                    background-color:#9fcdff;
                    border-radius:.3rem;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body><div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron align-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-primary"><h1 align="center">Incidencia número: $id</h1></div>
                <div class="row col-md-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2 text-primary">
                        Creado por el técnico:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-alert">
                        $agente
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2 text-alert">
                        Estado de la Avería:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-alert">
                        $estadoaveria
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2 text-alert">
                        Día y Hora de la visita:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-alert">
                        $diavisita - $horavisita
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                        Contacto:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        $contacto
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                        Dirección:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        $direccion - $cp - $poblacion - ($provincia)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                        Teléfono Fijo:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        $telefonofijo
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                        Teléfono Móvil:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        $telefonomovil
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="aparato">
                    <div class="row col-lg-12">
                        <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                            Marca:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            $marca
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-lg-12">
                        <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                            Aparato:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            $aparato
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-lg-12">
                        <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                            Descripción:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            $descripcion
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-lg-12">
                        <div class="offset-3 col-lg-2">
                            Observaciones:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            $observaciones
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

[image: así se ve en outlook o gmail]

Answer (score 0):

Si yo abro desde una nueva pestaña esta dirección: http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css en vez de ver el css me hace un HTTP 302 y me redirige al index, tendrías que corregir esa parte y probar de nuevo.

Al cliente de correo le pasa lo mismo. En su lugar usa un CDN para estos casos. Prueba a poner esto en su lugar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Además puedes meter fontawesome y lo que sea necesario, sólo navega y copia los códigos de cdnjs desde aquí: https://cdnjs.com/libraries

Comment: La url que pones arriba, no veo donde la tengo (http://tecnicos.serviciotecnicopro.es/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css) por otro lado, acabo de cambiar todo a CDN tal y como dices y me pasa 2 cosas.
1. En outlook no se ve bien, no aplica Bootstrap.
2. Al abrir en el explorador si que se ve bien.

Hay alguna opción de verlo bien en outlook? GRACIAS

Comment: Exacto. Ese es el siguiente paso con el que te encuentras cuando intentas enviar html por correo. 
Los clientes de correo no son navegadores web. No renderizan todo el contenido html como hace un navegador. Por limitación o seguridad.
Dentro de toda esa controversia que hay acerca de enviar html, aquí explican algunas de las limitaciones: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

No todos lo soportan igual, al final lo mejor es hacer un <table> como en los años 2000, o usar alguna web online que haga plantillas por ti. https://beefree.io/templates/ por ejemplo.